# List all files in a directory, then use command line to choose one file to work with - Python

Tags: python, command-line

I have used a for loop to list and print all the image files in my data directory. I now want to be able to use the command line to choose one of the files and proceed with my image analysis. Any suggestions would be helpful. This is my current program.

```
def find_fits_files(data_dir):
    """Creates image path in data directory.

        Args:
            data_dir(str, required):    Directory which contains FITs. images

        Returns:
            image_path(str):    Path to fits. image
            file(srt):    file name
    """
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(data_dir)
    for file in glob.glob("*.fits"):
        print('File name: ' + file)
    os.chdir(cwd)
    image_path = os.path.join(data_dir, file)
    return image_path, file
```

Comment: Please correct your code indentation. Also, can you expand on "choose one file" - how is this file chosen?

Comment: don't use `chdir`. Use `os.path.join` in your `glob` call

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre if my script is in one directory, and data is in another directory, which is not a sub directory of my script directory, how would os.path.join work? I have also heard that its inadvisable to change directories within a program, is this true?

Comment: Hi @jpp! I am a total beginner, so I'm not sure what is wrong with my indentation. My aim is to list all the files in the data_dir, and then use the command line to choose a particular file to add to my image_path. This way only that chosen file will be processed further.

Comment: Typically you would pass the file you want to process into the script as a command-line argument, rather than asking for it interactively. This way you can list the files using standard command-line tools (like “ls” on Linux/Mac/BSD and “dir” on Windows).

Comment: @nneonneo Thank you, that makes much more sense. I was over complicating things :)